# Hadoop mapreduce distribute records over datanodes by key

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

As a result of my mapreduce jobs i have several tables with integer PK. To avoid data transfering between nodes while joining this tables i want records to be distibuted over nodes by PK.

I found, that i can create custom partitioner, but it defines task id for record, and tasks with same id can run on different nodes in different job runs. So how can i set certain node for record key?